# WebRTC Working Process

Tags: ios, webrtc, p2p

I want to use video call on iOS,I have done R&D for doing this and found Webrtc is option for this.
   As i found WebRTC is Peer-To-Peer communication.And it's demo example is contain a server LINK.
  So my question is that If WebRTC is peer-to-peer then why this is using server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be unsafe for an app to listen to new connections all the time, you usually only want outbound connections in an app, inbound connections are found in server applications.
This is a problem for peer to peer, because if both peers only connect outbound, how will they ever establish a connection? The answer is that all peers connect to a signaling server. When starting a call, the peer signals the server that it wants to call another peer. The server can then let the other peer know that there is an incoming call.
It doesn't end here, there is still no connection, but at least both peers know that there will be one. Both peers will start generating ICE candidates now. Through ICE, peers find a route to establish the connection. Sometimes you can connect peer to peer now, but usually there's at least 1 firewall involved (most of the time it's more). In that case, the protocol tries a STUN server, which 'punches a hole' in the firewall (basically, it opens a port in a safe way). This covers 90% of all peer to peer connections, but there are still some cases where peer to peer connection is just not possible. This is where TURN comes in, it's a relay server that your peers can use to relay data to the other peers. The connection is not peer to peer this way.

Answer (score 1):

**WebRTC** can be used for multiple tasks, but real-time peer-to-peer audio and video (i.e., multimedia) communications is the primary benefit. In order to communicate with another person (i.e., peer) via a web browser, each person’s web browser must agree to begin communication, know how to locate one another, bypass security and firewall protections, and transmit all multimedia communications in real-time.

One of the biggest challenges associated with browser-based peer-to-peer communications is knowing how to locate and establish a network socket connection with another computer’s web browser in order to bidirectionally transmit multimedia data. The difficulties associated with this may not seem obvious at first, but let me explain further.

When you visit a web site, you typically enter a web address or click a link to view the page. A request is made to a server that responds by providing the web page (HTML, CSS, and JavaScript). The key here is that you make an HTTP request to a known and easily locatable (via DNS) server and get back a response (i.e., the web page).

Now let’s say I wanted to have a video chat with my dear ol’ mom. My mom’s computer is not a web server. Therefore, the problem is how do I make the request and actually receive her audio and video data directly, while also sending my audio and video data directly to her, but without going through an external server?

Got Help From [HERE](http://www.innoarchitech.com/what-is-webrtc-and-how-does-it-work/)